# LINQ to XML X-DOM internal implementation

Tags: c#, xml, performance, linq-to-xml

How is the LINQ to XML X-DOM from the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace internally implemented? (XNode, XElement, etc.)

Is it utilizing standard high-performing one-way XmlReader/XmlWriter from the other XML namespaces or something else?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm trying to figure out in which circumstances could or should be used as performance is always a concern.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you might find this interesting, I've used it and can provide a sample. http://blog.codebeside.org/archive/2008/09/08/streaming-xml-input-with-xelementreader.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Reflector (or, when that's no longer free, [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) :); no I'm not an employee - just spreading the word surreptitiously!) it appears all the load/save methods channel through to `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter`.
For example - XElement's implementation of `Load(Stream, LoadOptions)` does this:

```
public static XElement Load(Stream stream, LoadOptions options)
{
  XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = XNode.GetXmlReaderSettings(options);
  using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, xmlReaderSettings))
  {
    return Load(reader, options);
  }
}
```

And it's a similar story for all the other static methods - including Parse.

But then there is the `XStreamingElement` constructor - however I can't find any real usage of it outside of the `XElement` class itself.  Looks like this could be an optimised type for loading that, as yet, isn't used by much.

Equally, the Save and WriteTo methods ultimately use an `XmlWriter` instance - e.g:

```
public void Save(string fileName, SaveOptions options)
{
  XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = XNode.GetXmlWriterSettings(options);
  using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, xmlWriterSettings))
  {
    this.Save(writer);
  }
}
```

So at least from a performance point of view they started with the right types :)

Comment: Hi @bojanskr - note that accepting the answer won't award the bounty - not that I answered for the +50, but to help :).  I am well aware that by just mentioning this I could be breaking etiquette (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36871/etiquette-asking-questioner-to-award-bounty) - if so I offer my apologies in advance to you and the community :)

Comment: it was no problem awarding the bounty, but when I tried to click to award it it told me that I couldn't award the bounty for another 4 hours. So i waited out and awarded it. Hope now everything is OK.

Comment: @bojanskr - of course - completely forgot about the whole time limit thing, sorry :$